# Allow users to set the "base" profile that your stackexchange.com profile inherits from

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, stackexchange.com, profile-sync

[According to Emmett](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84365/how-do-i-change-my-stackexchange-com-account-aboutbox-on-the-aggregating-site/84503#84503), the aggregate [Stack Exchange Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/30498037-168a-4055-a849-0c31c2b1d863) you get on stackexchange.com is based on your eldest account, which is most often one's Stack Overflow account.

While we've managed to confirm that, it still hasn't changed the fact that my profile is dull, accurate, and monochromatic green. It should be either [cheery and colourful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note), or [*horribly* inaccurate towards anything that identifies me](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/85/grace-note).

I'd like to request that, in the same vein we can specify which account our [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/757/grace-note) inherits from, that we be allowed to select the profile for our main stackexchange.com profile to draw from.

Comment: actually I may be entirely and horribly wrong. I never actually noticed I had an actual profile on SE.com. The link I gave was for the account association thing I think, I'm actually not sure if it works the same way.

Comment: @Brandon It doesn't, because my Stack Overflow account is my lowest reputation account above 200.

Comment: Your profiles need more lasers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not an automatic sync (at this point - might put that back in if there's high demand), but you can now [update your profile on stackexchange.com using your profile from any Q&A site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275694/155160).