# How do I change my stackexchange.com account aboutbox (on the aggregating site)?

Tags: support, profile-page, stackexchange.com

As the title mentions, I want to change my about box on the main portal site (stackexchange.com),
it did copy it from my Stack Overflow account but, well, even after I changed that it stayed the same. I'm confused...

Comment: Related: [Allow users to set the base profile that your stackexchange.com profile inherits from](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81750/allow-users-to-set-the-base-profile-that-your-stackexchange-com-profile-inherit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The info at the top of your SE user page is pulled from your *oldest* profile, which, in your case (and most cases), is your StackOverflow profile. And, as Rebecca mentioned, it's cached for 24 hours.

So, as it currently works, you can change your SE about-me by changing your SO about-me, and then clicking "sync with oldest profile" on your SE user page.

Answer (score 1):

The data is cached for 24 hours.  Give it a bit of time and then check again.

Edit, I just looked and the info has since been updated.